# what's the purpose of customizing django models

Tags: python, django

I read the following code for customizing Document model.

```
class DocumentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def pdfs(self):
        return self.filter(file_type='pdf')

    def smaller_than(self, size):
        return self.filter(size__lt=size)

class DocumentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return DocumentQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)  # Important!

    def pdfs(self):
        return self.get_queryset().pdfs()

    def smaller_than(self, size):
        return self.get_queryset().smaller_than(size)

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    objects = DocumentManager() #overriding the default model manager
```

Now suppose i want to retreive files of type pdf and size less than 1000.
Then i need to do the following:

```
Document.objects.pdfs().smaller_than(1000)
```

But what's the use of doing this even when i could have simply obtained the desired result by filtering the default model manager 'objects' using the following command:

```
Document.objects.filter(file_type='pdf', size__lt=1000)
```

What is the difference in the execution of above two commands?

Comment: In this example they do the same. Custom methods like this are not super useful for stuff that can easily be done with regular filter and exclude methods. But there is stuff that might need more complex queries, or even raw SQL, and then it's convenient to use a model manager method or queryset method instead.

Comment: @HåkenLid can u provide an example of use case scenario, where i should use custom methods?

Comment: Methods are used to make your code easier to understand for humans reading it. If what you want to do is common enough or complicated enough that it makes sense to give it a name, then it could be a method. `Document.objects.search(query)` or `Document.objects.delete_outdated()` or `Document.objects.most_viewed_today()`.

Answer (score 1):

Manager and Queryset methods are defined and used in order to use repeatable code.

If your use case only happens once, perhaps you are better off being explicit in your query, however if you repeat the exact same code elsewhere, perhaps you are better off making it a manager/queryset method.